# Google Sheets Compare One Date to Another Date + 1 or 2 Days

Tags: date, datetime, if-statement, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm having trouble with this formula - which I feel should be easy but I'm not figuring it out.

I have a column with a request submission date and time and a column with an edit date and time. I'm looking at how many requests were edited exactly one day after it was submitted and another statistic one how many requests were submitted at least 2 days after submission. I think my issue is coming when I do the +1 or +2 to the date in the formula.

Please take a look of a sample of what I'm doing [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RWy08DMV-uhzSD_NDGUv8itgcZNZgZ__E57UbXhDu_8/edit#gid=0)...I'll also include a screenshot of the sheet below.

[image]

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",,{
 IF(INT(B2:B)>=INT(A2:A), "Y", "N"), 
 IF(DAYS(INT(B2:B), INT(A2:A))>=1, "Y", "N"), 
 IF(DAYS(INT(B2:B), INT(A2:A))>=2, "Y", "N")}))
```

[image]